# How do I bundle images into my static QT applications?

Tags: qt, static-linking

I'm building a tool that has some .bmp icon images in it. When I build the application statically, the images must be placed inside the application's folder to run, which defeats the purpose of having a static application in the first place. Is there a way to get the images to be rolled into the application during the build process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt has a [resource system](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/resources.html) that solves this problem.